# iOS views - how to remove excessive shadow?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that I'm nesting inside another `UIViewController` (iOS 4.3+),

it is displayed just fine except one thing - a lot of excessive shadow.
I have tried removing it with `setShadowRadius` etc, but no luck..

This is the code I use to create it:

```
RDPreviewViewController* preview = [[[RDPreviewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RDPreviewViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];

[preview.view.layer setShadowOpacity:0.0];
[preview.view.layer setShadowRadius:0.0];
[preview.view.layer setColor:nil];
[preview.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 264)];

[self.mainView addSubview:preview.view];
```

And here's the result:

[image]

How do I remove it?

Comment: You're loading in your VC from a NIB - are you sure the shadow isn't part of a PNG you've got in the NIB, or it's being applied to a subview of your `preview.view`?

Comment: The PNG I'm loading has a very subtle shadow, I want to keep it and disable the view's shadow.
I have only one view in RDPreviewViewController, an UIImageView with the background image. I tried using the quartz methods for its layer too, no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* - and this is a theory - that given what you've said that somehow your PNG image with the subtle shadow is being loaded multiple times. This is why your shadow appears much darker than you're expecting - several identical PNGs are being overlaid on top of each other.

The reason I think this is the case is that judging from the code you've posted you're not programatically applying a shadow, and views do not have a shadow by default. Of course, perhaps you are adding a shadow in your code elsewhere, but based on my own experience I think it looks as if somehow the same view (your image view) is getting added multiple times.

It might be helpful if you shared more of your code, if possible.

Comment: You were right. I was unintentionally calling the method several times. Removed the extra calls and the shadow looks just like in the PNG. Thanks!